# Validate ASP.NET Core Antiforgerytoken in Mvc4/WebAPI2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure an Mvc4/WebApi2 application to validate/decrypt ASP.NET Core generated Anti Forgery Tokens?

We want to be able to, from an ASP.NET Core application, make a validated request to the WebApi2 application using the AntiForgeryToken generated by ASP.NET Core which runs on the same domain (subdomain).

I believe (and could be wrong, so please correct me) that this is possible under normal WebApi --> WebApi or ASP.NET Core --> ASP.NET Core scenarios provided both apps run under the same domain (and thus have access to cookies). I can't seem to find instruction on how to do this ASP.NET Core --> WebApi.

Our ASP.NET Core application has data protection services set up via:

`services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem("SomeDirectory");`

The ASP.NET Core side has a working AntiforgeryToken implementation:
`services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");`

and

```
  app.Use(next => context =>
     {
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);

        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                            new CookieOptions {HttpOnly = false});

        return next(context);
     });
```

On the Mvc4/WebApi2 side we have a `DataProtectorShim` set up to allow it to be able to encrypt/decrypt OWIN cookies which both sides are able to operate on.

We tried to manually validate the anti forgery token/cookie but, unsurprisingly, it's unable to decrypt either (this was a stab in the dark):

```
AntiForgery.Validate(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"].Value, HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"]);
```

As far as I can tell, it looks like the `System.Web` `Antiforgery` class doesn't allow an injection point where we can push in a properly configured data protector/shim and always uses a MachineKey serializer to do this decryption. I'm aware of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery` library but am unsure as to if/how this may be able to help.

Our failed attempt at this yields:

`The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.`

Which makes sense in that we're not using the machine key for encryption on the ASP.NET Core side.

Is anyone aware of a way to set this up? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We’re having the exact scenario causing us an issue...

Comment: Nope - I don't think it's practical. DPAPI and machine key are completely different implementations that I later learned have no "bridge" to talk. Eventually we migrated everything over to ASP.NET Core. I'd be very interested to hear your findings though if you make any progress on this front. Sorry - Which I could help further.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, still trying to figure it out ;)  But I don't think it's achievable without iframes or clientside postbacks

Comment: That was my takeaway. I hesitate to say "impossible" but I think you'd have to implement your own middleware  decryption handler using DPAI.I'm guessing you're right and there is a good reason why no one has taken this on.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I was attempting to separate my app into different portions with a mix of dotnet core and .net mvc with a proxykit managing flow.  We have a login modal which is everywhere and can't be used anymore because of this.  The simplest solution was to redirect to the dotnet core app and have that handle logins.  All other shared endpoints are replicated to each app can handle its own antiforgery token/cookie.  Shame it can't be done.  There is an implementation in Owin.Antiforgery to have custom middleware but it would need to be modified to handle dataprotection....

Comment: Right, the lack of DI in the OWIN antiforgery class is the deal breaker. If you end up ever figuring it out, give me a shout... I'm interested to hear if you find anything else.